# New backups overwriting old backups in Linux Crontab

Tags: linux, cron, centos, backup

I am new to Linux. I am using CentOS 7. I found out that my new backup always replace my old backups. For example, backup on 15th of July 2019 will replace backup on 14th of July 2019.

```
# Create archive filename.
#day=$(date +%A)
day=$(date -d "$D" '+%d')
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$hostname-$day.tgz"
```

Could you point out what am I doing wrong with this command? Or could there
possibly be another reason that my backups would replace my old one that I did not see? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a date, hour / minute in the name of your archive so it wont replace your old backup.

`day = $(date +%F %l:%M)"`

Adding all the fields (day, date, time and year) will help you to store all backups without overwriting any.

Comment: When I try to run on my Linux terminal, it says "date: extra operand '%I:%M' ".

Comment: you need to enclose the FORMAT controls within double quotes, please try and let me know the output.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I try running day=$(date +"%F %l:%M") and the output is nazmin-ThinkCentre-M720s-2019-07-17 9:15. It worked.

Comment: That’s great! Can you please accept this answer as correct one :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any issue in the code but using just a combination of hostname + day as a key identifier to your filename is not unique and will replace the backup file last month.

And also there might be some other process that is removing the backup file like if you have log retention policy in the directory from where you store the backup.

Comment: Okay...could you give me suggestions for a better filename?

Comment: You can add the whole date, hostname + _ + year + month + day